# Getting undefined when to add a data node in replica set in mongodb from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication

I am trying to add a data node in replica set in MongoDB from Node.js but it is not adding the data node into the replica set

This is my code:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,//The modules importing
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSet = require('mongodb').ReplSet,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    assert = require('assert');

//The ip address of my machine and port number 
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://192.168.0.10:27217/test', function(err, db) {
    console.log(".....");

    // Use the admin database for commands
    var adminDb = db.admin();
    console.log(".....Going");

    // Default replica set conf
    var conf = {
                _id: "rpl0",
                members: [
                    {
                     _id: 2,
                     host: "192.168.0.10:27217"
                    },
                    {
                      _id: 2,
                      host: "192.168.0.10:27317"
                    },
                    {
                      _id: 3,
                      host: "192.168.0.10:27417"
                    },
                    {
                      _id: 4,
                      host: "192.168.0.7:27017"
                    }
             ]
        };
    //The command for adding the member
       adminDb.command({replSetConfig: conf}, function(err, info) {
            console.log(info);
        });
    })
```

This is what I am getting the output:

```
....
.....Going
undefined
```

I don't understand what wrong I am doing.

Comment: Is there an error? ``console.log(err)``?

Comment: //This is the error: { MongoError: no such command: 'replSetConfig', bad cmd: '{ replSetConfig: { _id: "rpl0", members: [ { _id: 2, host: "192.168.0.10:27217" }, { _id: 2, host: "192.168.0.10:27317" }, { _id: 3, host: "192.168.0.10:27417" }, { _id: 4, host: "192.168.0.7:27017" } ] } }'

Comment: Here you go, it's an invalid command. Consult MongoDB manual for proper command.
Also, every time you ask for help, please provide versions of software you are using - in this case MongoDB version.

Comment: I am using Mongodb 3.4 version . This is specified in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/#rs.add rs.add() provides a wrapper around some of the functionality of the replSetReconfig database command and the corresponding mongo shell helper rs.reconfig().

Comment: Seems the right command is ``replSetReconfig`` NOT ``replSetConfig`` as in your example.